How write correctly a Workbook in a HttpServletResponse using apache.poi
I'm trying to create a file xlsx after having created a workbook using apache.poi.
If I write it on disk, the file is created correctly but if I try to write on a response, I get always a file bigger than the one created on disk and it appears like to be corrupted.
This is my code

public void getFile(@RequestBodyRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {


    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";

    response.reset();
    response.resetBuffer();
    String fileName = "test.xlsx";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=%s", fileName);
    
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    Workbook workbook = dcservice.getRequest(request);

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        workbook.write(baos); 
        byte[] content = baos.toByteArray(); 

        response.setContentLength(content.length); 

        try (ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
            out.write(content);
            out.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (workbook != null) {
            try {
                workbook.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

I use swagger and the problem appears in every browser so it is not browser dependant.
Can someone help me?
